# Suppose that X ⊆ Y with |Y | = n and |X| = m. Compute the number of subsets of Y that contain X.

Tags: combinatorics

Shouldn't it be ${n}\choose{m}$ (combinations) my teacher said it's wrong please give a proper explanation.

for example:

$\{a,b,c\}$ subsets containing $\{a,b\}$ would be ${3}\choose{2}$=3
that would be {a,b} and $\{a,b,c\}$

Comment: You are on the right track, but you need some perspective. Start with a small example. Y={1,2,3,4,5}, X={1,2}. All the subsets that contain X will include X, X + 1 element, X + 2 elements and Y. How many of those subsets can you form?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question let's look at a valid subset that should be counted, the subset must:

- contain all the elements in $X$
- contain some / non / all the elements that are not in $X$ but in $Y$ i.e. subsets of $Y/X$

So the number of subsets that we are looking for is the same number of subsets from $Y/X$:
$$2^{|Y/X|}= 2^{n-m}$$

Answer (score 0):

It should be $2^{n-m}$. The reason for this is that $Y\setminus X$, the set of elements in $Y$ but not in $X$, contains $n-m$ elements. For each of these, one can choose whether it is to be included or not in a set $T\supseteq X$. Every such choice gives one subset $T$ of $Y$ containing $X$ and every subset $T$ of $Y$ containing $X$ is obtained for one such choice.